# Rails 4- Complex model validation (has_many, through)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, nested-forms

I am trying to validate the "name" attribute in my Ingredient model. However, when I add validates :name, :uniqueness => true in my Ingredient model, it does not validate the name (can insert ingredient with same name). The ingredient model has a complex relationship with other model. Please see the code below.

My ultimate goal is to allows user to create ingredient if the ingredient does not exist in the Ingredient table. If the ingredient already existed, used the ingredient id for quantity. If anyone has any idea how to achieve that, please provide the solution to it. Thanks in advance.

ingredient.rb

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :quantities
    has_many :recipes, through: :quantities

    validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
end
```

quantity.rb

```
class Quantity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ingredient
  belongs_to :recipe

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient,
                                :reject_if => :all_blank

  validates :ingredient, :uniqueness => true
end
```

recipe.rb

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :quantities,
                dependent: :destroy
    has_many :ingredients, 


                :through => :quantities

        accepts_nested_attributes_for :quantities, 
                                        reject_if: :all_blank, 
                                        allow_destroy: true

        accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
end
```

view section for creating Ingredient:

```
%strong Ingredients:
  %fieldset#recipe-ingredients
  %br
    = f.fields_for :quantities do |builder|
      = render 'recipe/quantity_fields', f: builder
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'add ingredient', f, :quantities, 'data-association-insertion-node' => '#recipe-ingredients', 'data-assoication-insertion-moethod' => "append", :wrap_object => Proc.new{|quantity| quantity.ingredient.build ; quantity}
            %br
```

Ingredient controller:

```
class IngredientController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_ingredient, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /ingredients
  # GET /ingredients.json
  def index
    @ingredients = Ingredient.all
  end

  # GET /ingredients/1
  # GET /ingredients/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /ingredients/new
  def new
    @ingredient = Ingredient.new
  end

  # GET /ingredients/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  def create
    @ingredient = Ingredient.new(ingredient_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @ingredient.save
        format.html { redirect_to @ingredient, notice: 'Ingredient was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @ingredient }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @ingredient.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /ingredients/1
  # PATCH/PUT /ingredients/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @ingredient.update(ingredient_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @ingredient, notice: 'Ingredient was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @ingredient }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @ingredient.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /ingredients/1
  # DELETE /ingredients/1.json
  def destroy
    @ingredient.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to ingredients_url, notice: 'Ingredient was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_ingredient
      @ingredient = Ingredient.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def ingredient_params
      params.require(:ingredient).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

Comment: How does it not validate? You're getting duplicated entries?

Comment: Duplicated entries. (Eg. I can insert ingredient with same name multiple time)

Comment: With the same case? Sure you don't need :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}?

Comment: all my entries are in lower case. I have tried :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a known issue probably a bug. Check this: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20676